# DateTimePicker's format is not correct when I set value from GUI

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making WPF Application using DateTimePickaer as MVVM pattern.

I have to set value with "yyyy/MM/dd HH" format because this app is for japanese.

(I should not to show the Minutes and Seconds in GUI but I have to get value that I set 00 to Minutes and Seconds)

But If I control the DateTimePickar from GUI, that value format changes to "MM/dd/yyyy HH".

If I set to that value in app's logic, I can get value with correct format.

My sammple is there.

//View

```
<xcad:DateTimePicker FormatString="yyyy/MM/dd HH" FontSize="11" Format="Custom" Value="{Binding DateTimeStart}" Margin="47,62,254,223" />
<Button Content="ShowValue!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="76" Margin="72,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Click="OnClickOpen"/>
```

//CodeBehinde

```
private void OnClickOpen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mMainViewModel.DateTimeStart);            
}
```

//ViewModel

```
private string DateTimeStartVal = DateTime.Now.ToString().Substring(0, DateTime.Now.ToString().IndexOf(':')) + ":00:00";
public string DateTimeStart
{
    get { return DateTimeStartVal; }
    set
    {
        DateTimeStartVal = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(':')) + :00";
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeStart");
    }
}
```

In this app, you get value with "yyyy/MM/dd HH:00:00" format when you start and push button.

But next, If you control DateTimePicker from GUI and you push button, you get value with "MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00" format.

I want to get value with "yyyy/MM/dd HH:00:00" format when I control that from GUI, too.

What should I do?

Comment: I want the solution. If I get any answer, I'll happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the type of `DateTimeStartVal` to DateTime type.

Answer (score -1):

//CodeBehinde

```
private void OnClickOpen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mMainViewModel.DateTimeStart.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(':')) + :00");            
}
```

//ViewModel

```
private string DateTimeStartVal = DateTime.Now.ToString().Substring(0, DateTime.Now.ToString().IndexOf(':')) + ":00:00";
public string DateTimeStart
{
    get { return DateTimeStartVal; }
    set
    {
        DateTimeStartVal = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeStart");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your advice! But I can not understand your code. This problem is that if I control DateTimePicker from GUI, I get the value with "MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00". Maybe your code is not this problem's solution. If my English is bad, very sorry.